# Read first line of file without encoding

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I want to read text files that can have different encodings for different users (assume all supported by some standard library codec or another) using Python. The trouble is that the encoding is specified *within* the file -- on the first line, like this:

`ISO8859-2
33847
60 minut|10
a|67
a có¿ dopiero|122
a figê|170
...`

The encoding, as you can see, is `ISO8859-2` for this particular file. As far as I know, we are supposed to specify the encoding with the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open%20builtin#open) function to be able to read from a file. Not specifying the encoding, `readline()` method for file object throws a `UnicodeDecodeError`. But I cannot figure out how to obtain the encoding from line #1 of the file, if I cannot read it in the first place.

I am hoping there is a solution to this apparent puzzle. Any help finding it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file with the option `errors="surrogateescape"` to suppress the error. Then you can read the first line which should be ASCII readable.

```
# create a test file in ISO-8859-2 with the header
import codecs

filename = "iso8859-2.txt"
header = codecs.encode("ISO8859-2\n")
textBytes = bytearray((32,33,171,187)) # using graphems Ť and ť

# the dictionary to translate your headers to valid encoding strings
encodings = { "ISO8859-2": "ISO-8859-2" }
encoding = ""

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(header)
    f.write(textBytes)

# yes, it's unreadable !!
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        f.readline()
except: 
    print("right, wrong encoding")

# use the option "surrogateescape"
with open(filename, encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    encoding = f.readline()[0:-1]

# and succeed
with open(filename, encoding=encodings[encoding]) as f:
    print(f.readline())
    print(f.readline())
```